# A fair die is rolled $7$ times. What is the probability of seeing less than $2$ aces? (ace $= 1$)

Tags: probability

A fair die is rolled $7$ times. What is the probability of seeing less than $2$ aces? (ace $= 1$)

I'm not entirely sure if I'm approaching this question correctly.

The answer I've come up with is $1 - (5/6)^7$

I did the complement minus the probability of rolling a one on every turn. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "the probability of rolling a $1$ on every turn" is $\left( \frac 16\right)^7$, though I'm not sure why that should be relevant to the problem.

Comment: You've computed the probability that an ace shows up on at least one roll, which is not at all what is required.  You want to compute the probability that either an ace never shows up, or an ace shows up exactly once.

Comment: This is binomial distribution, and you need the probability of < 2 successes. That is just $\displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{1} {7 \choose j} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^j \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7 - j}$. **Details:** The success probability is $1/6$ (getting a 1). You want the probability for 0 or 1 successes. Now check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution.

Answer (score 0):

> The answer I've come up with is $1−(5/6)^7$
>
> I did the complement minus the probability of rolling a one on every turn.

That is actually 1 minus the probability for rolling anything-other-than-one on every turn.

Which is the probability for *seeing more than zero aces*, and as such, not what you require.

---

The complement of "less than 2" is "2 or more".

Which is still not actually useful.

---

You seek the probability of rolling none or one ace among seven rolls.

The probability for rolling no aces is $\phantom{(5/6)^7}$.

The probability for rolling *some arrangement* of exactly one ace among seven rolls is $\phantom{7(1/6){(5/6)}^6}$.

Add them together.